# Error "The following filters could not choose their formats: Parsed_waveform_0" when trying to convert an image into a waveform

Tags: mac, ffmpeg

This is what I have so far

> ffplay -i 'JJJ_V-Look1_N1.0.tiff' -vf waveform=filter=aflat:scale=ire:graticule=green:flags=numbers+dots

And I am getting the error

> The following filters could not choose their formats: Parsed_waveform_0
>   Consider inserting the (a)format filter near their input or output.

Answer (score 0):

The flat modes only work with YUV formats and the framework is unable to decide on a pixel format to convert to. So, set one manually.

```
ffplay -i 'JJJ_V-Look1_N1.0.tiff' -vf format=yuvj444p,waveform=filter=aflat:scale=ire:graticule=green:flags=numbers+dots
```